# How to edit and read data in a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to query a SharePoint list and want to use the data to be displayed in a usercontrol that I have created.

Earlier I had the data coming from a database.

Now I need to modify it to work with a SharePoint list.

Can you please guide me.

Grace.

Comment: In what way do you need guidance?
Is it related to how to query a list in SharePoint with the SPQuery object? Please tell us what you need help with...

Comment: In addition: are you attempting to query the list from within a SharePoint application, or are you attempting to access it from somewhere else via SharePoint's Lists.asmx endpoint?  I'm guessing the latter, but figured it would be a good idea to check.

Comment: Johan You got me right. I am trying to query a SharePoint List and am not using it for external application. I have a web part with a user control mostly text boxes. I need to populate the list data to the text boxes.

Comment: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "myfieldName")%>. Earlier I have this in the .ascx. Now I need to have the data "myfieldName" coming from a SharePoint List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SPList list = null;
SPListItemCollection LIC = null;
SPListItem listItem = null;

using (SPSite mainSite = new SPSite("http://sitewhereyourlistis"))
{
    using (SPWeb mainWeb = mainSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        list = mainWeb.Lists["ListNameHere"];

        //**You will most likely want to limit your return to a single record so I have created the caml to do so with the List Item ID
        String caml = String.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><Value Type=\"Counter\">{0}</Value></Eq></Where>", ListItemID);

        SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
        qry.Query = caml;
        LIC = list.GetItems(qry);
        listItem = LIC[0];


        //**Here is where you will fill your textboxes
        txtTextBoxName.Text = listItem["ColumnNameHere"].toString();


        //**The above statement likes to error out if the value is null so I like to use a custom Application Helper Function to prevent things like this.
        //**My actual call to get the data would look like this.

        txtTextBoxName.Text = EnsureTextValue(listItem, "ColumnNameHere");
        // I added the Function Definition Below 

    }
}

public String EnsureTextValue(SPListItem item, String param)
{
    String tmp = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        tmp = item[param].ToString();
    }
    catch { "Run Debug Method or Whatever Here" }
    return tmp;
}
```

I am not sure if I missed anything but this should get you close.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi 20Seconds Thanks for your help. Can you please tell me how to edit the content in SharePoint list.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to Query the SharePoint List

```
            using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb)
            {
                SPList mylist = web.Lists["listName"];
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='columnName' /><Value Type='Text'>" + strXYZ+ "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                SPListItemCollection items = mylist.GetItems(query);
                tempDT = items.GetDataTable();
                return tempDT;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get Distinct Values for the column Click [Here](http://sharepointlearningmaterial.blogspot.com/2009/09/sharepoint.html)

To edit the values in the list there is a nice post [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/programmingsharepointlist08212009051742AM/programmingsharepointlist.aspx)